# Is it risky to book with Qatar Airways?

Tags: air-travel, planning, cancellations, qatar-airways

I am looking to fly mid-July on Qatar Airways round trip between Cape Town, South Africa and Paris, France. With the political situation at the moment, would there be any recourse for potential flight cancellations?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your question to remove the part asking if there's a risk to using this route, since that's really a matter of personal opinion. None of us has a crystal ball so nobody can say how much the political situation with Qatar will change in the next few weeks.

Comment: I was in Qatar last week. Seemed pretty normal to me. I wouldn't worry about it personally. Just regional politics.

Answer (score 8):

**You'll be fine.**  Qatar Airways is flying more or less normally, albeit with slightly longer flight times than usual, and your flights are not to/from/via/over any of the countries imposing sanctions.

The only theoretical risk is that the current conflict deteriorates into outright war, but that's *highly* unlikely.

Comment: Both Paris-Qatar and Capetown-Qatar would normally fly over countries imposing sanctions. Due to the sanctions, they won't. It doesn't change the bottom line that you'll be fine.